# express 4.0 , express-session with odd warning message

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to work through setting up a nodejs app using express 4.x. After stumbling through the middleware-removal issues, I finally got it working.

however, there was a couple of warning messages in the following line of code :

```
app.use(session({secret: '<mysecret>'})
```

these warnings were :

```
Sun, 29 Jun 2014 12:45:10 GMT express-session deprecated pass resave option; default value will change at lib\config\express.js:55:11

Sun, 29 Jun 2014 12:45:10 GMT express-session deprecated pass saveUninitialized option; default value will change at lib\config\express.js:55:11
```

in the documentation, the default values for resave and saveUninitialized are true.

so, changing the code to read

```
app.use(session({secret: '<mysecret>', 
                 saveUninitialized: true,
                 resave: true}));
```

got rid of the warnings.

So, to get to the point of the question:

why should I have to pass these values in if they are the default values, and why don't I have to pass in the other options ?

Comment: because these default values will change and, when they do, you can avoid errors that can cause by explicitly passing them to the middleware

Comment: I love how they helpfully DON'T tell you what the default options are

Comment: Both the `resave` and `saveUnitialized` are booleans which default to `true` in 1.7.2: https://github.com/expressjs/session

Comment: @cfs : It should be `saveUninitialized`. I copied what you posted and waster 45 mintues trying to figure out wh the warning isn't going away. Later I realized there was a spelling mistake. lol :D

Comment: Sorry about the wasted time Maverick :) Unfortunately, the comment is too old for me to edit, otherwise I'd fix my typo :/

Comment: Before blindly setting these values to true/false, you should consult the driver you're using to see how they handle the settings. For folks using connect-mongo, see here https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo#lazy-session-update

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As the warnings say, the default values will change so they want to ensure that by setting the values explicitly now, you won't run into unexpected behavior when the defaults do change (in the near future).

Comment: oh, so the default values for these two parameters are going to change sometime ? That makes much more sense! thanks.

Comment: legend has it, still going to change soon :)

Comment: From the future here. Still going to change soon :)

Answer (score 55):

I found issue useful:

https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/56

```
app.use(session({
    secret: cookie_secret,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Comment: thanks for answering the question in the form of code...  don't see that enough around here

Comment: Nice. Also, I would recommend to take a look at the docs. In my case it was better to set them to `false` ( https://github.com/expressjs/session#resave, https://github.com/expressjs/session#saveuninitialized ).

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough rep to add this as comment. I added this for my default value of Ben's answer.

```
secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || '<mysecret>',
```

Answer (score 2):

```
app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: 'eg[isfd-8yF9-7w2315df{}+Ijsli;;to8',
  duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  ephemeral: true,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Comment: Works for me, maybe the session needed just some extra settings. Thanks