# Facebook-authentication is failing in module passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I've installed the example from this [repo](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/tree/master/examples/login), after adding the callback URL to my Facebook app and getting the app_id and app_secret into my app.js. I get this error when trying to run my app:

```
Tue, 16 Sep 2014 15:14:41 GMT express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option at app.js:59:9

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at Function.app.listen (C:\Users\Jack\Documents\GitHub\passport-facebook\examples\login\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:552:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jack\Documents\GitHub\passport-facebook\examples\login\app.js:101:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I've looked after similar issues but wasn't able to find any, what is causing this? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Something is already listening on the port, choose another. As for the deprecation message, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477035/express-4-0-express-session-with-odd-warning-message) should help.

Comment: `app.listen(PUT_SOME_OTHER_PORT);`