# Node JS session error: express-session deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I have the following in my node js file

```
var express = require('express');
var util = require('./lib/utility');
var partials = require('express-partials');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var session = require('express-session');

/* abstracted some code */

app.use(session({
  genid: function(req) {
    return genuuid(); // use UUIDs for session IDs
  },
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```

When I start the server, I get

```
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option server.js
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option server.js
```

I am having a hard time figuring out what is deprecated? I copied the example from https://github.com/expressjs/session

When I try to load the page I get:

> ReferenceError: genuuid is not defined at app.use.session.genid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [express 4.0 , express-session with odd warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477035/express-4-0-express-session-with-odd-warning-message)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to define the `genuuid` function somewhere. The `express-session` readme is assuming you have already implemented that.

Regarding the warnings, you need to explicitly set the `resave` and `saveUninitialized` options in your session configuration object.

Comment: "The express-session readme is assuming you have already implemented that."

Why in the world would they *assume* that!?  Then why not call it something like `write_your_uuid_func_here()` ?

Anyway, if you don't have a specific reason to *need* the UUID format, this does uniqueness just fine: `require('crypto').randomBytes(48).toString('hex');`

You can also install various `npm` packages to do UUIDs.

Answer (score 50):

From [express 4.0 , express-session with odd warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477035/express-4-0-express-session-with-odd-warning-message/29585850#29585850)

As the warnings say, the default values will change so they want to ensure that by setting the values explicitly now, you won't run into unexpected behavior when the defaults do change (in the near future).

```
app.use(session({
    secret: cookie_secret,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Answer (score 8):

Add these flags-

```
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true
```

inside your -  `app.use(session({});`
and it should work fine.

Comment: So this way the module itself generates a UUID right? thanks

Answer (score 8):

Use this , hope it will help

```
app.use(session({
    name : 'codeil',
    secret : 'something',
    resave :false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie : {
            maxAge:(1000 * 60 * 100)
    }      
}));
```

Comment: Hi Ravi Chandola, welcome. Please consider formatting properly the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Add

```
{
     resave: true,
     saveUninitialized: true
}
```

to your session middleware

Answer (score 3):

```
app.use(session({ secret: 'anything', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));/
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `maxAge` for session cookie duration:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: '<session_secret>', 
  resave: true, 
  saveUninitialized: true,
  maxAge: 3600000   // 1 hour (in milliseconds)
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use(
  session({
    name: "code",
    secret: "something",
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 100,
    },
  })
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a new version of ***express*** and define genid function somewhere in your app or use ***uuid*** package instead

Answer (score 0):

```js
req.logout(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

It's working 100%

Answer (score 0):

```
const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
  secret: 'your-secret-key',
  resave: false, // or true if you want to save the session even if it wasn't modified
  saveUninitialized: false // or true if you want to save a new session that hasn't been modified
}));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.