# Getting error while running the node.js server side script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting the following error while trying to run node server by using the command `node server` using node.js.

> Error:

```
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option server
.js:18:9
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUnini
tialized option server.js:18:9
C:\xampp\htdocs\cit_node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:196
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (C:\xampp\htdocs\cit_node\node_module
s\express\lib\router\route.js:196:15)
    at EventEmitter.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (C:\xampp\htdocs\cit_node\
node_modules\express\lib\application.js:481:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\cit_node\server.js:20:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:961:3
```

I am explaining my server side code below.

> server.js:

```
var port=8888;
var express=require('express');
var http=require('http');
var morgan         = require('morgan');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); // the session is stored in a cookie, so we use this to parse it
var app            = express();
var server=http.createServer(app);
var admin=require('./route/route.js');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                     // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json())    // parse application/json
app.use(methodOverride());                  // simulate DELETE and PUT
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({secret:'abcx'}));
app.post('/login',admin.adminlogin);
app.get('/session',admin.session);
//app.post('/logout',admin.logout);
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('view/index.html');
});
server.listen(port);   
console.log('Magic happens on port'+port);          // shoutout to the user
```

Before some time i was able to run this but dont know why it is throwing this type of error.My package.json file is given below.

```
{
  "name": "Gofasto",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.13.3",
    "morgan": "1.6.1",
    "body-parser": "1.14.1",
    "method-override": "2.3.5",
    "socket.io":"1.3.7",
    "mongojs":"1.4.1",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.0",
    "express-session": "1.11.3"
  }
}
```

> route.js:

```
var mongo = require('mongojs');
var database='go_fasto';
var collections=['user'];
var db=mongo("127.0.0.1:27017/"+database, collections);
exports.adminlogin=function(req,res){
    var username=req.body.username;
    var password=req.body.password;
    db.user.findOne({
        user_name:username,
        raw_password:password
    },function(err,docs){
        if(!err){
            if(docs){
                console.log('docs',docs);
                ses=req.session;
                ses.username=docs.user_name;
                ses.user_type=docs.user_type;
                ses.email_id=docs.email;
                ses.dept_id=docs.dept_id;
                res.send(docs);
            }
        }
        if(err){
            res.send("could not login");
        }
    });
}
/*exports.logout=function(req,res){
    req.session.destroy(function(err){
if(err){
console.log(err);
}
else
{
res.redirect('/');
}
});
}
*/
```

I am using the node version `4.2.1`.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: please see https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/56 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477035/express-4-0-express-session-with-odd-warning-message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comment look at this: https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/56

You need to specify the `resave` and the `saveUninitialized` options:

```
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'abcx',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Then the error refers to this line of code:

```
app.get('/session',admin.session);
```

Because `admin.session` is undefined in `./route/route.js`

Comment: @ Michelem: Ok i added and the warning are gone but still error is there which has explained in my post.