# Express-session Deprecation warnings even if values are explicitly defined

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express-session for my node JS application and I keep getting the following 3 deprecation warnings when I run the app:

express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option

```
node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide
saveUninitialized option node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5
express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5
```

I have my session defined like this:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "akjjkjnisaiuu8998323jdkadsih892rhoisdfasl",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60000
    }
}));
```

From what I read on the documentation, if I have resave, secret and saveUnitialized explicitly efined in the session, the warnings should go away. Am I missing something else?

I am running the app using `nodemon app.js` could that be it?

EDIT: I already have the options in the warnings already defined in my app.js, so the other (duplicate) question does not help...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [express 4.0 , express-session with odd warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477035/express-4-0-express-session-with-odd-warning-message)

Comment: @Raymond I already have those options defined in my app.js but I am still seeing those deprecation warnings...